How to convert a numbered list into a list with static ("unformatted") numbers that don't change automatically when the list is edited?
I often get Word documents converted from books in PDF format that have complicated nested chapter and chapter section numberings in the headers of the document, and I need to convert these numbered list headers to regular headers that have numbers as static text, because otherwise, when I make changes to the document, Word starts renumbering every header in the entire book and that screws up the numbering of the chapters and subsections.
I once saw a trick that does exactly what I need. It involved selecting the list numbers in the headers then pasting them back into the list as "unformatted" text using the Paste Special feature (In the Home / Clipboard section of the ribbon), but I have forgotten the exact sequence used in the trick. Apparently, I'm missing a step, because I am unable to SELECT or COPY the list numbers. When I try to do so by dragging the pointer, Word thinks I am trying to drag the indentation of the list. In other words, Word will not allow me to select the numbers in the numbered list in the way necessary for the trick to work. I can select the numbers of the numbered list by simply clicking on them and then do things like change the font, but I can't select the numbers with a view to copying them and pasting them back into the list without the unwanted formatting. The formatting leads to massive unwanted renumbering of the list with every edit, and so I need to get rid of it. I want to FREEZE the chapter numbers and the section numbers permanently.
Has anyone seen this trick before? If so, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong when I try to select the list numbers and then paste them?
This trick DOES NOT involve making changes in File => Options in the Cut, Copy Paste section of Advanced Word Options. If you recommend that, then you haven't understood what I'm asking. The trick I'm trying to remember does not require permanent changes to the way lists behave in Word when copied and pasted.
Thanks.

Change the font.
Then run the following macro.
Sub NumbersToText()
    ' Charles Kenyon
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.convertnumberstotext
   ActiveDocument.ConvertNumbersToText
End Sub

For information on how to use a macro, see one of these:

Instructions for installing macros from forums or websites by Word MVP Graham Mayor
Install vba procedures from forums by Greg Maxey


Thanks, Charles. I'm glad tp know this trick. Do you know how to limit the conversion to a single list?
I know for certain that there is a way to do this with Paste Special => Unformatted. That limits the change to a single list and does not require VBA code, and I really want to figure out how that is done, but I'm still glad to get the VBA snippet you provided.

Sorry. I do not.
